# HWIOauthBundle - Facebook Login - Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I had implemented HWIOauthBundle + FOSUserBundle into my app, and it's working, partially.

Login is working perfectly with and without facebook but, if I login normally with a user that doesn't exists or with a wrong password, it will redirect me to /connect route (because of HWIOauthBundle).

How can I solve this problem? If something is wrong, to see what /login_check from FOSUserBundle is returning. I don't want to login with facebook.

My security.yml code:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: '/login'
                login_path: /connect
                failure_path: /connect

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
            logout: true
            anonymous: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
                # by default, the feature is enabled by checking a
                # checkbox in the login form (see below), uncomment the
                # following line to always enable it.
                #always_remember_me: true


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/shipment, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My routing.yml code:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

facebook_login:
    path: /login/check-facebook

# main login.
AppBundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

FrontendBundle:
    resource: "@FrontendBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

FOSUserBundle:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

FOSMessageBundle:
    resource: "@FOSMessageBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
    prefix:   /messenger

MyDinxxUserBundle:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the facebook path from '/login' to '/login/check-facebook' in security.yml.

```
oauth:
    resource_owners:
        facebook: '/login/check-facebook'
```

Comment: It's working somehow... It's still redirecting me, but now on /login route, and without errors. I think it should redirect me on that page, but with the errors up.

Comment: Ok, the last idea: try to change '/connect' to '/login' in security.yml and routing.yml.

Comment: All /connect routes with /login?